# puppet server hostname does not match certificate - can't authenticate.

Tags: ssl, authentication, puppet, puppetmaster

I know this question has been asked before in many different variant. I read all the post related to the problem but I cannot get agent and master talking to each other. I boot up 2 vm via vmwork station both running on linuxmint 17.

I'll start this thread by telling what's my /etc/hosts and /etc/hostname in client and puppetmaster looks like.

In my client's vm my host name in /etc/hostname looks like the following:

```
puppetclient
```

my client's vm hosts in /etc/hosts looks like the following:

```
127.0.0.1 localhost
127.0.1.1 puppetclient
192.168.75.143 puppetmaster
```

In my master's vm /etc/hostname looks like the following:

```
puppetmaster
```

My master's vm /etc/hosts looks like the following:

```
127.0.0.1 localhost
127.0.1.1 puppetmaster
192.168.75.144 puppetclient
```

My /etc/puppet/puppet.conf in my master looks like the following:

```
[main]
logdir=/var/log/puppet
vardir=/var/lib/puppet
ssldir=/var/lib/puppet/ssl
rundir=/var/run/puppet
factpath=$vardir/lib/facter
templatedir=$confdir/templates
prerun_command=/etc/puppet/etckeeper-commit-pre
postrun_command=/etc/puppet/etckeeper-commit-post

[master]
# These are needed when the puppetmaster is run by passenger
# and can safely be removed if webrick is used.
ssl_client_header = SSL_CLIENT_S_DN
ssl_client_verify_header = SSL_CLIENT_VERIFY
```

my /etc/puppet/puppet.conf in my client looks like the following:

```
[main]
logdir=/var/log/puppet
vardir=/var/lib/puppet
ssldir=/var/lib/puppet/ssl
rundir=/var/run/puppet
factpath=$vardir/lib/facter
templatedir=$confdir/templates
prerun_command=/etc/puppet/etckeeper-commit-pre
postrun_command=/etc/puppet/etckeeper-commit-post

[master]
# These are needed when the puppetmaster is run by passenger
# and can safely be removed if webrick is used.
ssl_client_header = SSL_CLIENT_S_DN
ssl_client_verify_header = SSL_CLIENT_VERIFY

[agent]
server=puppetmaster
```

I have many variant of puppet.conf during my search and I don't feel like posting here. One of the variant is to have `server=puppetmaster`in [main] in both my client and master's vm. Anyways, for all the puppet.conf variants i tried, my first error when I run `sudo puppet agent --test` is always `warning: unable to fetch my node definitoin, but agent run will continue:`the error after that is different for each variant of puppet.conf I implement. Can anyone tell me the right configuration for my setup?

Thanks

Comment: Have you created site.pp file with at least `node "puppetclient" {}` or `node default {}` section?

Answer (score 2):

It seems that you installed and ran your puppet master first and then changed the hostname.

On puppet master execute:
`puppet config print certname`
This will show the certname your master uses. It should be equal to your hostname.

You can verify common name in master's certificate if it matches your hostname:

```
openssl x509 -noout -subject -in $(puppet config print ssldir)/certs/$(puppet config print certname).pem
```

Also I recommend using FQDN in puppet configuration.
If hostname differs the easiest way is just to remove or rename SSL dir:

```
mv $(puppet config print ssldir){,_}
```

And restart your puppet master.
You'll need to do that on client node as well, because CA will change.

Comment: This. Also take note that the `certname` defaults to what `facter fqdn` determines, not `facter hostname`. As such, `/etc/hostname` is only half the truth. On Linux `dnsdomainname -f` is the source for the `fqdn` fact, and can be skewed by different influences besides `/etc/hosts`.